# Валидация формы

Tags: css3, css, html, html5

Добрый вечер.

Сделано так: **http://jsfiddle.net/k6uu47yk/**

Можно сделать, чтобы фон примера становился так же зеленым после правильного ввода формата, но сам текст изменился допустим на "Соответствует формату".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:
http://jsfiddle.net/k6uu47yk/1/

Comment: @Nasty Pacman, Спасибо большое, а можно после убирания фокуса убрать "Супер"?

Comment: Конечно, можно: http://jsfiddle.net/k6uu47yk/2/

Решает псевдокласс :focus